# is it possible to drop not exact duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is it possible to drop not exact/ similar duplicates?

E.g In this case I'd like to drop the duplicates within 0.1 lat and long.

```
site_df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["12345", "Wrexham Cwtch", "52.10", "-2.06"], ["12354", "Horse & Hound", "52.21", "-1.95"], ["12435", "Round Of Gras Badsey", "52.33", "-1.99"]]),
                   columns=['Site Number', 'Site Name', 'Longitude', 'Latitude'])

site_df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["52938", "Valkyrie Café Bar", "53.22", "-3.00"], ["12435", "Round Of Badsey", "52.33", "-1.99"], ["12345", "Cwtch", "52.11", "-2.00"]]),
                   columns=['Site Number', 'Site Name', 'Longitude', 'Latitude'])

matched_sites = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["12345", "Wrexham Cwtch", "52.10", "-2.06"], ["12435", "Round Of Gras Badsey", "52.33", "-1.99"], ["52938", "Valkyrie Café Bar", "53.22", "-3.00"]]),
                   columns=['Site Number', 'Site Name', 'Longitude', 'Latitude'])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can compute the distances with [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) and use them to drop the rows of one of the DataFrames for [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

threshold = 0.1

# longitude within threshold
d1 = cdist(site_df_1[['Longitude']].astype(float), site_df_2[['Longitude']].astype(float)) < threshold
# latitude within threshold
d2 = cdist(site_df_1[['Latitude']].astype(float), site_df_2[['Latitude']].astype(float)) < threshold

# both within threshold
mask = d1&d2
# array([[False, False,  True],
#        [False, False, False],
#        [False,  True, False]])

# drop "duplicated" coordinates and concat
out = pd.concat([site_df_1, site_df_2.loc[~mask.any(axis=0)]])

print(out)
```

*NB. be aware geographic coordinates are not linear, so a difference of 0.1 will me much smaller close to the poles than close to the Equator.*

Output:

```
  Site Number             Site Name Longitude Latitude
0       12345         Wrexham Cwtch     52.10    -2.06
1       12354         Horse & Hound     52.21    -1.95
2       12435  Round Of Gras Badsey     52.33    -1.99
0       52938     Valkyrie Café Bar     53.22    -3.00
```